# Randomly no video with same ffmpeg command

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming, rtmp

Here is command:

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost/myapp/obs -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 32k -c:v libx264 -f flv rtmp://localhost/hls/obs_low
```

My RTMP server records all published streams, so I can view them all. Strange thing is, while `rtmp://localhost/myapp/obs` is streaming, if I run the above ffmpeg command, it's only audio in output file, no video. And in terminal output:

`Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (aac (native) -> aac (libfdk_aac))`

But if I run same command again, there could be the video. Randomly, video is there or not. If video is there, I see this output in terminal:

`Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (libfdk_aac))`

Full output of 'audio-only' command: http://pastebin.com/zL0ctvTZ

Full output of 'successful' command: http://pastebin.com/DQ1XJ1wM

Comment: Just now run above ffmpeg command 20 times in a row. There was video only 12 times. 8 times = just audio.

Comment: Sounds like interleaving gap is large. Try with `-analyzeduration 1G -probesize 50M` before `-i rtmp://...`

Comment: You're right. Thanks, now every record has video and sound. Any advices on which values should I use just to make sure there always would be video and audio? P.S. If you write an answer, I'll accept it ofcourse.

Comment: what is full console output? If it's MPEG then eah you might need larger analyzeduration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the interleaving gap is large. Try with `-analyzeduration 1G -probesize 50M -i rtmp://...` The values present a tradeoff between missing out on streams and the delay in the start of capture, so I'd suggest doing trials. Default value for both analyzeduration and probesize is `5M`, so try with slightly larger values till you consistently don't get a stream dropout. Experiment with probesize first. You may not need to specify the other one.